# Scrollbar interrupts hover state, CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I'm trying to create a mega nav only I have a small bug I can't quite figure out.

My parent category on the left has a number of items and is scrollable, when you hover over 1 item, a subnav appear but as you move your cursor towards it, when the cursor hits the scrollbar the subnav dissapears as the hover state is no long active.

I've made a fiddle to show what I mean and any advice or workarounds would be a great help!

http://jsfiddle.net/j45zx3tr/1/

```
nav nav .products-nav .mega-nav .parent-cat {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to make the navigation scrollable? It works perfectly fine without the scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/j45zx3tr/5/

Comment: There's a lot of navigation items @Kovah, the fiddle is just for demonstation purposes

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want a quick fix, you can add `direction:rtl`; to your mega-nav ul and the scrollbar will be out of your way!

```
header #site-nav nav .mega-nav ul {
    background: #e6571d;
    width: 235px;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Here is the edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j45zx3tr/7/).
If that's not what you want, you should use JS as @Mark said, if you dont want to write the  timeout stuff yourself, you could use "[hoverIntent](http://rawgit.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent/master/jquery.hoverIntent.html)" jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

just you changed `height :210px`

```
nav nav .products-nav .mega-nav .parent-cat {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 210px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/j45zx3tr/3/)

Comment: It seems OP doesn't want to resize the `.parent-cat`, but only prevent scrollbar for cancelling `:hover` statement.

Comment: I can understand just a minutes sir @EdenSource

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JS. It's impossible with pure CSS.

User can scrolling a long time.

You should processing `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for `li`.

Inside `mouseenter` - just `display:block` for `sub-nav`, but inside `mouseleave` - starting timer for 500 ms and then `display:none` for `sub-nav`.

And processing for parent `ul` - if timer has not expired - clean it - so window `sub-nav` will be displayed while scrolling.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought @Mark, do you think something like a simple timeout would work?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
$(".parent-cat li").hover(function () { $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active").find(".sub-nav").css("display", "none");
    $(".active").find(".sub-nav").css("display", "block");
});

$(".products-nav").hover("", function(){
    $(".active").find(".sub-nav").css("display", "none");
});
```

[Here is your *updated* **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j45zx3tr/6/)